# Flutter web app in the Android webview calling method of injected Android object

Tags: javascript, flutter, web, android-webview

I have this situation: there is the android/Kotlin app, which has the webview, which loads the Flutter web app from the Internet URL.

To be clear - this is not the case of having webview in the Flutter. Quite opposite - Flutter is used to build the web app, which is rendered within the Android webview.

We followed google instruction to create the webview interface: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

I.e. Kotlin creates the Android object within the webview.

I can access this Javascript Android object from the Chrome Debug tools console, while debugging the webview.

I.e. the Android / Kotlin part is ok.

However the Android object is not found when being called from the Flutter web app. I crosschecked and Flutter web app can call the alert function.

Can someone give me the idea how to call the injected Android object?

Code for the Flutter web app:

```
void webViewExit() {
  print("User command: Exit webview.");

  try {
    js.context.callMethod("Android.onExitPressed");
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Result in the chrome devtools console:

```
User command: Exit webview.
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'apply' on null
```

﻿
​
This works directly from within the devtools console attached to the webview:

```
Android.onExitPressed();
```

This also works (from the Flutter webview webapp):

```
void webViewExit() {
  print("User command: Exit webview.");

  try {
    // js.context.callMethod("Android.onBackPressed");
    js.context.callMethod("alert", ["Calling Alert works!"]);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the workaround:

I added the predefined function into the static index.html page of the Flutter web app:

index.html

```
  ...
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }

    // Added JS function starts here

    function onExitPressed() {
      console.log("Called onExitPressed in webview JS.");
      Android.onExitPressed();
    }
    // Added JS function ends here

  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  ...
```

Now the call from Flutter web app works:

```
void webViewExit() {
  print("User command: Exit webview.");

  try {
    js.context.callMethod("Android.onExitPressed", []);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

I assume the reason is that the Android object is injected after the dart's main.dart.js is loaded and initiated.